# Help with PIVOT query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, pivot

I have a table with below structure :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AUDIT_SCHEMA_VERSION](
    [SCHEMA_VER_MAJOR] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SCHEMA_VER_MINOR] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SCHEMA_VER_SUB] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SCHEMA_VER_DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [SCHEMA_VER_REMARK] [varchar](250) NULL
);
```

some sample data (seems problem with sqlfiddle.. so putting some sample data):

```
INSERT INTO [AUDIT_SCHEMA_VERSION]([SCHEMA_VER_MAJOR],[SCHEMA_VER_MINOR],[SCHEMA_VER_SUB],[SCHEMA_VER_DATE],[SCHEMA_VER_REMARK])
VALUES(1,6,13,CAST('20130405 04:41:25.000' as DATETIME),'Stored procedure build')
INSERT INTO [AUDIT_SCHEMA_VERSION]([SCHEMA_VER_MAJOR],[SCHEMA_VER_MINOR],[SCHEMA_VER_SUB],[SCHEMA_VER_DATE],[SCHEMA_VER_REMARK])
VALUES(1,6,13,CAST('20130405 04:41:25.000' as DATETIME),'Stored procedure build')
INSERT INTO [AUDIT_SCHEMA_VERSION]([SCHEMA_VER_MAJOR],[SCHEMA_VER_MINOR],[SCHEMA_VER_SUB],[SCHEMA_VER_DATE],[SCHEMA_VER_REMARK])
VALUES(1,7,13,CAST('20130405 04:41:25.000' as DATETIME),'Stored procedure build')
INSERT INTO [AUDIT_SCHEMA_VERSION]([SCHEMA_VER_MAJOR],[SCHEMA_VER_MINOR],[SCHEMA_VER_SUB],[SCHEMA_VER_DATE],[SCHEMA_VER_REMARK])
VALUES(1,10,13,CAST('20130405 04:41:25.000' as DATETIME),'Stored procedure build')
INSERT INTO [AUDIT_SCHEMA_VERSION]([SCHEMA_VER_MAJOR],[SCHEMA_VER_MINOR],[SCHEMA_VER_SUB],[SCHEMA_VER_DATE],[SCHEMA_VER_REMARK])
VALUES(1,12,13,CAST('20130405 04:41:25.000' as DATETIME),'Stored procedure build')
INSERT INTO [AUDIT_SCHEMA_VERSION]([SCHEMA_VER_MAJOR],[SCHEMA_VER_MINOR],[SCHEMA_VER_SUB],[SCHEMA_VER_DATE],[SCHEMA_VER_REMARK])
VALUES(1,12,13,CAST('20130405 04:41:25.000' as DATETIME),'Stored procedure build')
INSERT INTO [AUDIT_SCHEMA_VERSION]([SCHEMA_VER_MAJOR],[SCHEMA_VER_MINOR],[SCHEMA_VER_SUB],[SCHEMA_VER_DATE],[SCHEMA_VER_REMARK])
VALUES(1,16,13,CAST('20130405 04:41:25.000' as DATETIME),'Stored procedure build')
INSERT INTO [AUDIT_SCHEMA_VERSION]([SCHEMA_VER_MAJOR],[SCHEMA_VER_MINOR],[SCHEMA_VER_SUB],[SCHEMA_VER_DATE],[SCHEMA_VER_REMARK])
VALUES(1,16,13,CAST('20130405 04:41:25.000' as DATETIME),'Stored procedure build')
INSERT INTO [AUDIT_SCHEMA_VERSION]([SCHEMA_VER_MAJOR],[SCHEMA_VER_MINOR],[SCHEMA_VER_SUB],[SCHEMA_VER_DATE],[SCHEMA_VER_REMARK])
VALUES(1,16,13,CAST('20130405 04:41:25.000' as DATETIME),'Stored procedure build')
INSERT INTO [AUDIT_SCHEMA_VERSION]([SCHEMA_VER_MAJOR],[SCHEMA_VER_MINOR],[SCHEMA_VER_SUB],[SCHEMA_VER_DATE],[SCHEMA_VER_REMARK])
VALUES(1,16,13,CAST('20140417 18:10:44.100' as DATETIME),'Stored procedure build')
INSERT INTO [AUDIT_SCHEMA_VERSION]([SCHEMA_VER_MAJOR],[SCHEMA_VER_MINOR],[SCHEMA_VER_SUB],[SCHEMA_VER_DATE],[SCHEMA_VER_REMARK])
VALUES(2,5,0,CAST('20140417 18:14:14.157' as DATETIME),'Stored procedure build')
INSERT INTO [AUDIT_SCHEMA_VERSION]([SCHEMA_VER_MAJOR],[SCHEMA_VER_MINOR],[SCHEMA_VER_SUB],[SCHEMA_VER_DATE],[SCHEMA_VER_REMARK])
VALUES(2,6,0,CAST('20140417 18:14:23.327' as DATETIME),'Stored procedure build')
INSERT INTO [AUDIT_SCHEMA_VERSION]([SCHEMA_VER_MAJOR],[SCHEMA_VER_MINOR],[SCHEMA_VER_SUB],[SCHEMA_VER_DATE],[SCHEMA_VER_REMARK])
VALUES(2,7,0,CAST('20140417 18:14:32.270' as DATETIME),'Stored procedure build')
INSERT INTO [AUDIT_SCHEMA_VERSION]([SCHEMA_VER_MAJOR],[SCHEMA_VER_MINOR],[SCHEMA_VER_SUB],[SCHEMA_VER_DATE],[SCHEMA_VER_REMARK])
VALUES(2,8,0,CAST('20141209 09:38:40.700' as DATETIME),'Stored procedure build')
INSERT INTO [AUDIT_SCHEMA_VERSION]([SCHEMA_VER_MAJOR],[SCHEMA_VER_MINOR],[SCHEMA_VER_SUB],[SCHEMA_VER_DATE],[SCHEMA_VER_REMARK])
VALUES(2,9,0,CAST('20141209 09:43:04.237' as DATETIME),'Stored procedure build')
INSERT INTO [AUDIT_SCHEMA_VERSION]([SCHEMA_VER_MAJOR],[SCHEMA_VER_MINOR],[SCHEMA_VER_SUB],[SCHEMA_VER_DATE],[SCHEMA_VER_REMARK])
VALUES(2,10,0,CAST('20141209 09:45:19.893' as DATETIME),'Stored procedure build')
INSERT INTO [AUDIT_SCHEMA_VERSION]([SCHEMA_VER_MAJOR],[SCHEMA_VER_MINOR],[SCHEMA_VER_SUB],[SCHEMA_VER_DATE],[SCHEMA_VER_REMARK])
VALUES(2,13,0,CAST('20150323 14:54:30.847' as DATETIME),'Stored procedure build')
INSERT INTO [AUDIT_SCHEMA_VERSION]([SCHEMA_VER_MAJOR],[SCHEMA_VER_MINOR],[SCHEMA_VER_SUB],[SCHEMA_VER_DATE],[SCHEMA_VER_REMARK])
VALUES(1,10,13,CAST('20130405 04:41:25.000' as DATETIME),'Stored procedure build')
INSERT INTO [AUDIT_SCHEMA_VERSION]([SCHEMA_VER_MAJOR],[SCHEMA_VER_MINOR],[SCHEMA_VER_SUB],[SCHEMA_VER_DATE],[SCHEMA_VER_REMARK])
VALUES(1,16,14,CAST('20140417 18:11:07.977' as DATETIME),'Stored procedure build')
INSERT INTO [AUDIT_SCHEMA_VERSION]([SCHEMA_VER_MAJOR],[SCHEMA_VER_MINOR],[SCHEMA_VER_SUB],[SCHEMA_VER_DATE],[SCHEMA_VER_REMARK])
VALUES(1,16,15,CAST('20140417 18:11:13.130' as DATETIME),'Stored procedure build')
INSERT INTO [AUDIT_SCHEMA_VERSION]([SCHEMA_VER_MAJOR],[SCHEMA_VER_MINOR],[SCHEMA_VER_SUB],[SCHEMA_VER_DATE],[SCHEMA_VER_REMARK])
VALUES(2,2,0,CAST('20140417 18:12:11.200' as DATETIME),'Stored procedure build')
INSERT INTO [AUDIT_SCHEMA_VERSION]([SCHEMA_VER_MAJOR],[SCHEMA_VER_MINOR],[SCHEMA_VER_SUB],[SCHEMA_VER_DATE],[SCHEMA_VER_REMARK])
VALUES(2,3,0,CAST('20140417 18:12:33.330' as DATETIME),'Stored procedure build')
INSERT INTO [AUDIT_SCHEMA_VERSION]([SCHEMA_VER_MAJOR],[SCHEMA_VER_MINOR],[SCHEMA_VER_SUB],[SCHEMA_VER_DATE],[SCHEMA_VER_REMARK])
VALUES(2,4,0,CAST('20140417 18:12:48.803' as DATETIME),'Stored procedure build')
INSERT INTO [AUDIT_SCHEMA_VERSION]([SCHEMA_VER_MAJOR],[SCHEMA_VER_MINOR],[SCHEMA_VER_SUB],[SCHEMA_VER_DATE],[SCHEMA_VER_REMARK])
VALUES(1,13,13,CAST('20130405 04:41:25.000' as DATETIME),'Stored procedure build')
INSERT INTO [AUDIT_SCHEMA_VERSION]([SCHEMA_VER_MAJOR],[SCHEMA_VER_MINOR],[SCHEMA_VER_SUB],[SCHEMA_VER_DATE],[SCHEMA_VER_REMARK])
VALUES(1,16,13,CAST('20130405 04:41:25.000' as DATETIME),'Stored procedure build')
INSERT INTO [AUDIT_SCHEMA_VERSION]([SCHEMA_VER_MAJOR],[SCHEMA_VER_MINOR],[SCHEMA_VER_SUB],[SCHEMA_VER_DATE],[SCHEMA_VER_REMARK])
VALUES(2,11,0,CAST('20141209 09:45:58.993' as DATETIME),'Stored procedure build')
INSERT INTO [AUDIT_SCHEMA_VERSION]([SCHEMA_VER_MAJOR],[SCHEMA_VER_MINOR],[SCHEMA_VER_SUB],[SCHEMA_VER_DATE],[SCHEMA_VER_REMARK])
VALUES(2,12,0,CAST('20141209 09:46:50.070' as DATETIME),'Stored procedure build');
```

Here is the <kbd>[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9f84d)</kbd> with some sample data.

Can someone with a T-sql expertise guide me on how to achieve the final result ? I know that `PIVOT` (with dynamic columns) will be the right approach, but cant figure it out.

Expected results :

[image]

So far, I have below :

```
select row_number() over (
        partition by CONVERT(varchar(10), SCHEMA_VER_DATE, 110) order by SCHEMA_VER_DATE 
        ) as rownum
    ,CONVERT(varchar(10), SCHEMA_VER_DATE, 110) as UPG_DATE
    ,CONVERT(varchar(1), SCHEMA_VER_MAJOR) + '.' + CONVERT(varchar(2), SCHEMA_VER_MINOR) + '.' + CONVERT(varchar(2), SCHEMA_VER_SUB) as SCHEMA_VER
from audit_schema_version
where SCHEMA_VER_REMARK like 'Stored procedure build'
order by UPGRADE_DATE
```

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is a bit messy to get the final result because you have multiple `SCHEMA_VER` for each date. Before I demonstrate how to do this with dynamic SQL, I'll first show how to do it with static code to get the logic correct. In order to get the final result you can utilize both pivot and unpivot.

But first, I'd change your original query to use the following:

```
select 
    row_number() over (
    partition by CONVERT(varchar(10), SCHEMA_VER_DATE, 110) order by SCHEMA_VER_MAJOR, SCHEMA_VER_MINOR, SCHEMA_VER_SUB
    ) as minrownum
, row_number() over (
    partition by CONVERT(varchar(10), SCHEMA_VER_DATE, 110) order by SCHEMA_VER_MAJOR desc, SCHEMA_VER_MINOR desc, SCHEMA_VER_SUB desc
    ) as maxrownum
,CONVERT(varchar(10), SCHEMA_VER_DATE, 110) as UPG_DATE
,CONVERT(varchar(1), SCHEMA_VER_MAJOR) + '.' + CONVERT(varchar(2), SCHEMA_VER_MINOR) + '.' + CONVERT(varchar(2), SCHEMA_VER_SUB) as SCHEMA_VER
from audit_schema_version
where SCHEMA_VER_REMARK like 'Stored procedure build';
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9f84d/16). I used `row_number()` to get the first and the last `SCHEMA_VER` for each date. This is needed so you can concatenate only those values together for the comment.

Then I would use a temp table to store the rows that have a `minrownum` and `maxrownum` of 1. The temp table would contain the `upg_date` and the `comment`. This comment column contains a concatenated string of the pair of the `SCHEMA_VER` for each date.

```
create table #srcData
(
    upg_date varchar(10),
    comment varchar(500)
);
```

The code to populate the temp table would then be:

```
;with cte as
(
  select 
        row_number() over (
        partition by CONVERT(varchar(10), SCHEMA_VER_DATE, 110) order by SCHEMA_VER_MAJOR, SCHEMA_VER_MINOR, SCHEMA_VER_SUB
        ) as minrownum
    , row_number() over (
        partition by CONVERT(varchar(10), SCHEMA_VER_DATE, 110) order by SCHEMA_VER_MAJOR desc, SCHEMA_VER_MINOR desc, SCHEMA_VER_SUB desc
        ) as maxrownum
    ,CONVERT(varchar(10), SCHEMA_VER_DATE, 110) as UPG_DATE
    ,CONVERT(varchar(1), SCHEMA_VER_MAJOR) + '.' + CONVERT(varchar(2), SCHEMA_VER_MINOR) + '.' + CONVERT(varchar(2), SCHEMA_VER_SUB) as SCHEMA_VER
  from audit_schema_version
  where SCHEMA_VER_REMARK like 'Stored procedure build'
)
insert into #srcData
select distinct
    c1.UPG_DATE,
    comment 
        = STUFF((
                  SELECT ' - ' + c2.SCHEMA_VER 
                  FROM cte c2
                  WHERE (c2.minrownum = 1 or c2.maxrownum = 1)
                    and c1.upg_date = c2.upg_date
                  order by c2.minrownum
                  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') 
from cte c1
where c1.minrownum = 1 or c1.maxrownum = 1;
```

This first pass through your data gets you:

```
|   upg_date |           comment |
|------------|-------------------|
| 03-23-2015 |            2.13.0 |
| 04-05-2013 |  1.6.13 - 1.16.13 |
| 04-17-2014 |   1.16.13 - 2.7.0 |
| 12-09-2014 |    2.8.0 - 2.12.0 |
```

Now you still need to get a count of each date for the year and the full concatenated comment. This would be where unpivot comes into play.  You could use the following code to create the full comment for each year and to get the count.

```
select distinct 
    Yr =  right(s1.upg_date, 4),
    cnt = count(*) over(partition by right(s1.upg_date, 4)),
    fullcomment 
            = STUFF((
                      SELECT '; ' + s2.comment 
                      FROM #srcData s2
                      WHERE right(s1.upg_date, 4) = right(s2.upg_date, 4)
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') 
from #srcData s1;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9f84d/32). The data now looks like:

```
|   Yr | cnt |                       fullcomment |
|------|-----|-----------------------------------|
| 2013 |   1 |                  1.6.13 - 1.16.13 |
| 2014 |   2 |  1.16.13 - 2.7.0;  2.8.0 - 2.12.0 |
| 2015 |   1 |                            2.13.0 |
```

As you can see you've got multiple columns that need to be pivoted, so you can unpivot both the `fullcomment` and `cnt` column into multiple rows. This can be done using the UNPIVOT function or CROSS APPLY. I'd prefer cross apply here because you'll want to concatenate values together to create the new column names:

```
;with cte as
(
    select distinct 
        Yr =  right(s1.upg_date, 4),
        cnt = count(*) over(partition by right(s1.upg_date, 4)),
        fullcomment 
                = STUFF((
                          SELECT '; ' + s2.comment 
                          FROM #srcData s2
                          WHERE right(s1.upg_date, 4) = right(s2.upg_date, 4)
                          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') 
    from #srcData s1
) 
select [2015], [2015_comment], [2014], [2014_comment], [2013], [2013_comment]
from
(
    select c.col, val
    from cte d
    cross apply
    (
        values 
            (Yr, cast(cnt as nvarchar(50))),
            (Yr+'_comment', fullcomment)
    ) c (col, val)  
) d
pivot
(
    max(val)
    for col in ([2015], [2015_comment], [2014], [2014_comment], [2013], [2013_comment])
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9f84d/33).

Once you've got the logic, you can easily convert this to dynamic SQL.

```
-- get list of the columns
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(col) 
                    from #srcData
                    cross apply
                    (
                        select right(upg_date, 4), right(upg_date, 4), 2 union all
                        select right(upg_date, 4), right(upg_date, 4)+'_comment', 1
                    ) c (yr, col, so)
                    group by yr, col, so
                    order by yr desc, so desc
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query 
    = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' 
        from 
        (
            select c.col, val
            from
            (
                select distinct 
                    Yr =  right(s1.upg_date, 4),
                    cnt = count(*) over(partition by right(s1.upg_date, 4)),
                    fullcomment 
                            = STUFF((
                                      SELECT ''; '' + s2.comment 
                                      FROM #srcData s2
                                      WHERE right(s1.upg_date, 4) = right(s2.upg_date, 4)
                                      FOR XML PATH(''''), TYPE).value(''.[1]'', ''nvarchar(max)''), 1, 2, '''') 
                from #srcData s1
            ) d
            cross apply
            (
                values 
                    (Yr, cast(cnt as nvarchar(50))),
                    (Yr+''_comment'', fullcomment)
            ) c (col, val)  
        ) x
        pivot 
        (
           max(val)
           for col in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p '

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9f84d/34). Both versions will give you the result:

```
| 2015 | 2015_comment | 2014 |                      2014_comment | 2013 |      2013_comment |
|------|--------------|------|-----------------------------------|------|-------------------|
|    1 |       2.13.0 |    2 |  1.16.13 - 2.7.0;  2.8.0 - 2.12.0 |    1 |  1.6.13 - 1.16.13 |
```

Answer (score 5):

Adding explanation and a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c92b2/5.

The query bellow:
1. uses a subquery to select the min and max versions by date (min and max are applied to integers to guarantee that for instance 6 < 16)
2. Then Selects the year (to group later), Date (to order) and the min - max versions

```
SELECT LEFT(UPG_DATE, 4) AS Year
    , UPG_DATE
    , CONVERT(varchar(1), MIN_VER/1000000) + '.' + CONVERT(varchar(2), (MIN_VER/1000 - (MIN_VER/1000000)*1000)) + '.' + CONVERT(varchar(2), MIN_VER%1000)
        + ' - ' + CONVERT(varchar(1), MAX_VER/1000000) + '.' + CONVERT(varchar(2), (MAX_VER/1000 - (MAX_VER/1000000)*1000)) + '.' + CONVERT(varchar(2), MAX_VER%1000) AS Versions
INTO #Versions
FROM (
    SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), SCHEMA_VER_DATE, 112) as UPG_DATE
        , MIN(SCHEMA_VER_MAJOR*1000000 + SCHEMA_VER_MINOR*1000 + SCHEMA_VER_SUB) AS MIN_VER
        , MAX(SCHEMA_VER_MAJOR*1000000 + SCHEMA_VER_MINOR*1000 + SCHEMA_VER_SUB) AS MAX_VER
    FROM audit_schema_version
    WHERE SCHEMA_VER_REMARK like 'Stored procedure build'
    GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar(10), SCHEMA_VER_DATE, 112)
) Versions;
```

Next, as each column will be repeated (year and year_COMMENT), two columns are selected to identify the data. The number of dates are counted to know the number of upgrades and Versions are grouped by year, stuffing so it gets all into one line. This gives us the final table that will be used to pivot.

```
SELECT Year, Year + '_COMMENT' as Year_COMMENT
    , COUNT(Year) AS Upgrades
    , STUFF((SELECT ' ; ' + SUB.Versions
                FROM #Versions SUB
                WHERE SUB.Year = V.Year
                ORDER BY UPG_DATE ASC
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(2000)')
            ,1,3,'') Versions
INTO #GroupedResults
FROM #Versions V
GROUP BY Year

SELECT * FROM #GroupedResults
```

Here are the results:

```
| Year | Year_COMMENT | Upgrades | Versions                         |
|------|--------------|----------|----------------------------------|
| 2013 | 2013_COMMENT | 1        | 1.6.13 - 1.16.13                 |
| 2014 | 2014_COMMENT | 2        | 1.16.13 - 2.7.0 ; 2.8.0 - 2.12.0 |
| 2015 | 2015_COMMENT | 1        | 2.13.0 - 2.13.0                  |
```

Next, a variable is filled with the columns, ordered as we want to display them:

```
DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(1000),
    @finalQuery VARCHAR(2000)

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(YEAR) + ',' + QUOTENAME(YEAR + '_COMMENT')
                    FROM #GroupedResults
                    GROUP BY YEAR
                    ORDER BY YEAR DESC
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(2000)')
    ,1,1,'')
```

Finally, the bellow query uses cross apply so we get:
1. The col column filled with the Year and Year_COMMENT values
2. The value column filled with the number of upgrades, in the lines corresponding to the years, and versions values, in the lines corresponding to the Year_COMMENTs
A pivot is used over the two resulting columns giving us the values (number of upgrades alternating with versions) over the col (Years alternanting with Year_COMMENTs)

```
set @finalQuery = N'SELECT ' + @cols + N' from 
             (
                select col, value
                from #GroupedResults
                cross apply
                (
                    SELECT CAST(Upgrades AS VARCHAR(200)), Year
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT CAST(Versions AS VARCHAR(200)), Year_COMMENT
                ) c (value, col)
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                Min(value)
                for col in (' + @cols + N')
            ) p1
            ; '

EXEC (@finalQuery);

DROP TABLE #Versions;
DROP TABLE #GroupedResults;
```

This returns the following results:

```
| 2015 | 2015_COMMENT    | 2014 | 2014_COMMENT                     | 2013 | 2013_COMMENT     |
|------|-----------------|------|----------------------------------|------|------------------|
| 1    | 2.13.0 - 2.13.0 | 2    | 1.16.13 - 2.7.0 ; 2.8.0 - 2.12.0 | 1    | 1.6.13 - 1.16.13 |
```